# Where can I see see the properties of an NS-Class?

Tags: objective-c, properties

Where can I see see the properties of an NS-Class? I really miss them in the Apple Class Reference.

Thanks a lot for a hint!

Comment: Wait, aren't properties included in the class reference? I am sure they are...

Comment: they are. stupid past me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample from the [Apple's UIView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html):

---

**backgroundColor**

The receiver’s background color.

`@property(nonatomic, copy) UIColor *backgroundColor`

`^^^^^^^^^ HERE`

**Discussion**

...

---

And if you look at the overview, it's there too:

```
backgroundColor  property
```